# How to project a value with known pace

Tags: statistics

I am working on a coding project that is tracking the total # of tweets someone does in a week, with stats that live update. I want to project "on track to hit: (number of tweets)" as the week progresses. Would I do this by simply calculating (avg tweets per day * 7) or current count + (avg * days remaining) or something else? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this very simple or rather complex, depending on how accurate you need to be. This is a somewhat straightforward (but not necessarily easy) machine learning problem.

1. Gather some actual tweet statistics for a lot of users
2. Assume some prediction model $T_{t+7} = f(T\subset\{T_0,...,T_t\})$
3. Split your data up into a training and test set. Fit the model to the training set, test accuracy on the test set.
4. Pick model with best test set performance.

An extension of your approach would be to have $f(t) = \sum_{i=t-L}^t \alpha_iT_i$ (linear model).